# Conditionally enable or disable o:cache through an attribute?

Tags: jsf, caching, omnifaces

I could not find any attribute to conditionally enable or disable `o:cache`. Is there any other way to accomplish this ?

Something like this:

```
<o:cache scope="application" disabled="#{someELexprsn}">
    ....
</o:cache>
```

I would like to disable o:cache based on some condition.

*(Actually I use this o:cache on a page that is used to display page for several type of entities but I want to enable cache only for pages of certain entities.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no attribute which enables you to disable the cache on a per-request basis. Feel free to open a [feature request](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues) in order to get it added to OmniFaces.

In the meanwhile, you could abuse the `reset` attribute.

```
<o:cache scope="application" reset="#{someELexprsn}">
    ....
</o:cache>
```

Under the covers, it will still cache it but it would be resetted everytime the EL expression evaluates `true`. In effects, it has exactly the desired effect as intented, although it is under the covers done in a clumsy way. That may be sufficient until the new attribute is been added by OmniFaces guys. The `disabled` attribute would instead of a reset perform a full pass-through of rendering (thus, in this particular example, the cached content would be still in application scope, but is simply not been rendered).

Comment: Added a feature request : https://code.google.com/p/omnifaces/issues/detail?id=241